# Google Places API , return a handle / reference to the object

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

I am new to the Google API / Places. I still haven't figured out how to get a return reference from the loaded script.

For example, I am loading the map like this and its working.

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_KEY&libraries=places&callback=Test" async defer></script>
```

Then it loads the javascript and calls "Test" function where I can get the map.
But the problem is that I wanna make a class/object for further "searches" when I have the library loaded. So can call a method with additional parameters nearbySearch etc.

But the problem is that is that I am now locked into 1 method instead of having a reference.

Some pseudo code you get a better understanding.

```
    Test = {
        Object : {},

        Load : function(){
            this.Object = new google.maps.Map....;
        },

        More : function(args){
            this.Object.nearbySearch("parameters_here" + args);
        }
    }

    Test.More("Paramentershere");
```

Is this possible, or what is the correct way when working with Google API?
Hopefully you understand what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need places API search in your JavaScript code you should follow a pattern:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(elem, options);
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

The documentation for place searches:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Code samples: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search